# How can I consume from a queue backed by any type of exchange?

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

I'm writing a message listener that needs to accept messages from a named Queue. Using spring-amqp, I'm wondering if it's possible to configure this listener such that consumption of messages via a queue will happen regardless of what its backing exchange type is.

For example:

```
<rabbit:admin id="amqpAdmin" connection-factory="reconciliationAmqpConnectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:queue id="queue" name="exampleQueue" />
```

This will bind this example queue to a direct exchange, but what if the consumer should bind the queue to either a direct, fanout, headers, or topic exchange? Essentially, I'm wondering if there is a way to decouple the consuming listener's queue binding from having to know the exact type of its backing exchange at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I understand the question.

There's no such thing as a "backing exchange".

Consumers consume from queues; they have no idea what the upstream exchange is or how the queue is bound. Yes, there is a default direct exchange that queues get bound to by name, but that's just for convenience; it is unusual to use that in production.

You create exchanges, queues, bindings and consumers consume from queues; producers send to exchanges.

Perhaps your confusion is because most examples show all the configuration in a single place.

You can build whatever upstream infrastructure you want but the key is that consumers consume from queues.

Take a look at the [Spring Integration sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml) for some config examples.

See the [stocks sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sample-apps.html) for some Java config examples.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I definitely was confused by the documentation showing configuration on both the consumer and producer ends... It makes it difficult to determine when things are necessary. I'll mark as answered because it pushed me in the right direction. =]